# Lazyloading images and SEO

Tags: seo, images

Lazyloading images with a noscript fallback. Should I expect any damage in the SERPs? 
The site is completely thumbnail based. Also should I put a smaller image size in the noscript fallback to increase crawlability?
We have nearly 1mil thumbs so it's a decision I'm hesitant to do. The reason why I'm thinking about it in the first place is because we're upping thumbail size about 50% which will add 10% of pagesize.

Comment: You're making references to a particular implementation(eg. the `noscript` comment; not all involve that) without actually telling us *which* you're using, which makes it kind of impossible to address. On the other hand, what @YardenST said overall.

Answer (score 1):

When using lazy image load make sure:

1. Use a technique that keeps the SRC attribute of the  tag so it will be transparent to search engines bots. (Many plugins use `data-src`.) Just like the when you use `<a>` tags for Ajax, you should keep the original `href` so bots can crawl the target location.
2. Use image site maps.

Comment: what about a noscript tag for the images?

Comment: you need to think this way:
use normal tag images.
if the client can run JavaScript, run the script causing the lazy loading. this way you don't need the fallback.